# Piped Stream Issue in Freemarker

Tags: java, blocking

I need to load and process a template in freemarker.  I am using a piped stream to read back the generated result by freemarker.

Sample code:

```
PipedInputStream pi = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream po = new PipedOutputStream(pi);
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(po);
configuration.getTemplate("xx").process(rootMap, writer);
```

The issue is that sometimes it's freezing inside freemarker procsss method.
No Error, no Exception, but it's not returning back from the `process` method.

If I convert the piped stream to a ByteArray stream, it works fine.

Am I using piped stream in correct way?

Comment: Why do you want to read back the generated result? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Arne: I want to read generated template and write it to another stream. (zip Stream).

Comment: Why not simply use a OutputStreamWriter on the zip stream?

Comment: @Arne: its a part of API, cannot touch :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, piped streams are designed to pass data between two threads. There is only a small buffer between the ends of the pipe. If you write into the piped output stream, your thread will be blocked if the buffer is full until another thread will read from the corresponding piped input stream. This will not work with just one thread.

From the Javadoc:

> Typically, data is read from a
>   `PipedInputStream` object by one
>   thread  and data is written to the
>   corresponding `PipedOutputStream` by
>   some  other thread.

So for small templates just use a `StringWriter`, for large ones you may use a `FileWriter` on a temp file created by `File.createTempFile()`.

Comment: thanks for the replay.

do you have any other solution for large templates? i can't write to temp file. (don't have Access)

Comment: @mohammed: Do you really not have access? Or do you simply not know the right location to write to? There's usually a temporary directory that you've got permission to, if you can figure out where (hint: look at the `java.io.tmpdir` property).

Comment: @Donal: Application running on a Server (OSGI) and i am not sure that i can write to file in customer environment.

Comment: @mohammed: Well, OSGi is currently outside my expertise (that may have changed by the end of the year) so I can't really advise from a position of knowledge, but I'd *really* suggest testing whether you can write in the directory given by that property. It's supposed to be a place you can write stuff (and which the OS will wipe from time to time).

Answer (score 1):

As Arne writes, the amount of buffer space in a piped stream is fairly small. If you can't use a buffer that can hold all of the data (whether in memory or on disk) then one thing you could try is to see if you can run the template processing in another thread with a piped stream sending the results back to the main thread where you're doing this.

```
PipedInputStream pi = new PipedInputStream();
final Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new PipedOutputStream(pi));
Thread worker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        configuration.getTemplate("xx").process(rootMap, writer);
    }
});
worker.start();
```

You might need to add `final` keywords to other variables to make this work in your real code. It depends on whether the variable `configuration`, the argument to `getTemplate` or the `rootMap` variable are local variables or instance (or class) variables.

(I could have subclassed `Thread` when specifying the thread's behavior of course, but I prefer to instantiate an interface – `Runnable` in this case – for such things.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it work.

```
final String uploadReportAsCsv = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
                        fileUploadReportTemplate, modelMap);

message.addAttachment("fileUploadProcessedReport.csv",
    new InputStreamSource() {
        //InputStreamResource from Spring is always returning an open stream,
        // thus we need to create this anonymous class.
        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new StringInputStream(uploadReportAsCsv);
        }
    }
);
```